# Task owner does not changes when Lead owner changes

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow create a task on the Lead. The lead when created is transferred to a Queue and then transfered to an user.

The Ownership of the task doesnt change to the new user. This is probably because when the lead is transferred to the queue, the ownership of task doesnt change as tasks cannot be assigned to a queue and when the ownership of the lead is changed to new user the task is still with the old user.

Is there a way to change the ownership of the task also to the new user and notify the user of the change?

Comment: Trigger or process builder flow i guess ...I dont think anything out of box here

Comment: Either that or you'll need a trigger to transfer all related tasks to the new owner when the previous owner of a Lead was the Queue and the new owner is a User.